# Extracting JSON object from BigQuery Client in AWS Lambda using Python

Tags: json, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, google-bigquery, aws-lambda

I am running a SQL query via the `google.cloud.bigquery.Client.query` package in AWS lambda (Python 2.7 runtime). The native BQ object extracted from a query is the `BigQuery Row()` i.e.,

> Row((u'exampleEmail@gmail.com', u'XXX1234XXX'), {u'email': 0, u'email_id': 1})

I need to convert this to Json, i.e.,

> [{'email_id': 'XXX1234XXX', 'email': 'exampleEmail@gmail.com'}]

When running locally, I am able to just call the python Dict function on the row to transform it, i.e.,

```
queryJob = bigquery.Client.query(sql)
list=[]
for row in queryJob.result():
    ** at this point row = the BQ sample Row object shown above **
    tmp = dict(row)
    list.append(tmp)`
```

but when I load this into AWS Lambda it throws the error:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 22; 2 is required

I have tried forcing it in different ways, breaking it out into sections etc but cannot get this into the JSON format desired.

I took a brief dive into the rabbit hole of transforming the QueryJob into a Pandas dataframe and then from there into a JSON object, which also works locally but runs into `numpy` package errors in AWS Lambda which seems to be a bit of a known issue.

I feel like this should have an easy solution but just haven't found it yet.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but you can use [the `TO_JSON_STRING` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_json_string) inside of the query itself to convert each row into a JSON string.

Comment: I tried this, but the export is still in the BigQuery Row() format, even if what inside is now formatted as a JSON string. What I'm trying to do is convert that Row format to JSON.

Comment: Right, you would still need to extract the content of each row object, but at least it would be in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this

`

```
L = []
sql = (#sql_statement)
query_job = client.query(sql)  # API request
query_job.result()
for row in query_job:
    email_id= row.get('email_id')
    email= row.get('email')
    L.append([email_id, email])
```

`